# Given a vector between points $A$ and $B$, how determine the coordinates of point $C$ when $AC$ is collinear to $AB$ and we know the length of $AC$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, problem-solving

Say we have a vector $\vec{v}$ that defines the chemical bond between two atoms, and whose components are known

$$
\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Lets define another vector $\vec{u}$ that is collinear to $\vec{v}$, which represents the same chemical bond but with a different length, and whose length is known

$$
\vec{u} = c \vec{v}
$$

From

$$
\lvert \vec{u} \rvert = \sqrt{(cv_1)^2 + (cv_2)^3 + (cv_3)^2}
$$

I was able to derive the following relationship (which I suppose for those who do linear algebra is a well-known quality of collinear vectors)

$$
\lvert \vec{u} \rvert = c \lvert \vec{v} \rvert
$$

Since the magnitudes of both vectors are known, we can find $c$ easily (the initial bond distance is of course known, and we are free to define the new bond distance as we please).

However, and perhaps this is trivial, what I want is to obtain a quantity that I can add to the specific atomic coordinates in my molecule. Say my system consists of two molecules, and I want to adjust the distance between these two molecules, by translating one of the molecules in a direction defined by the vector between one atom of molecule 1 and one atom of molecule $2$.

To implement this in my code, I suppose I have to work with the coordinates  themselves (since a vector on its own could be anywhere in space). So we have three sets of coordinates: atom $A$, initial atom $B$, and final atom $B$

$$
\begin{align}
A &= (A_x, A_y, A_z)\\[3mm]
B_i &= (B_{x,i}, B_{y,i}, B_{z,i})\\[3mm]
B_f &= (B_{x,f}, B_{y,f}, B_{z,f})
\end{align}
$$

Intuitively I want to set up a set of three linear equations, one for each coordinate, but I am unsure how to proceed. Additionally I sort of want to end up using the result $\lvert \vec{u} \rvert = c \lvert \vec{v} \rvert$ (because collinearity is included here....... and because I derived it, lol).

Any thoughts on how to solve this (I think) simple problem?

---

If I understood Narlin's answer correctly, we should have the following.

Given the unit vector

$$
\vec{w} = \frac{\vec{v}}{\lvert \vec{v} \rvert} = 
$$

and

$$
c = \frac{\lvert \vec{u} \rvert }{\lvert \vec{v} \rvert}
$$

we should have that

$$
(B_{f,x}, B_{f,y}, B_{f_z}) = (A_x, A_y, A_z) + \frac{\lvert \vec{u} \rvert }{\lvert \vec{v} \rvert} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}w_1 \\ w_2 \\ w_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Or, if we separate the coordinates into their own equations

$$
\begin{align}
B_{f,x} &= A_x + \frac{\lvert \vec{u} \rvert }{\lvert \vec{v} \rvert} w_1 \\[3mm]
B_{f,y} &= A_y + \frac{\lvert \vec{u} \rvert }{\lvert \vec{v} \rvert} w_2 \\[3mm]
B_{f,z} &= A_z +  \frac{\lvert \vec{u} \rvert }{\lvert \vec{v} \rvert} w_3 
\end{align}
$$

### Numerical example

Defining the points $A$ and $B_i$

$$
\begin{align}
A &= (0,0,0) \\[3mm]
B_i &= (0,2,4)
\end{align}
$$

we have that the vector $\vec{AB_i}$

$$
\vec{AB_i} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$

and $c=2$, we have that $\lvert \vec{AB_i} \rvert = 2\sqrt{5}$ and that $\lvert \vec{AB_f} \rvert = 4\sqrt{5}$. The unit vector $\vec{w}$ becomes

$$
\vec{w} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 5^{-1/2} \\ 2\cdot 5^{-1/2} \end{bmatrix}
$$

We then have everything to find the coordinates of point $B_f$.

Using the formula from Narlin's answer, I get that

$$
\begin{align}
B_{f,x} &= 0 + 2 \cdot 0 &= 0 \\[3mm]
B_{f,y} &= 0 + 2 \cdot 5^{-1/2} &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\[3mm]
B_{f,z} &= 0 + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5^{-1/2} &= \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}} 
\end{align}
$$

which is clearly wrong. The correct answer should be $B_f = (0,4,8)$.

Comment: Is $B_f$ the point $C$ in your question title?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, variable $c$ represents the length of the new vector. This is a change of variable from the ones used in the question. Here, $c=\Vert u \Vert$. The OP used $\Vert u \Vert$ to represent the new vector length.  $$\\$$You know coordinates for A and B. You know the length between A and B.
You also know the length $c$ of the new vector. Define a unit vector as follows: $$w=(B-A)/|(B-A)|$$ The new point $C = A + c\cdot w$. Create a numeric example and this should work for you.
$$\\$$**(edit)**
You know coordinates for A and B. You know the length between A and B. In your example, the length between A & B is $s=\Vert(B-A)\Vert=2\sqrt{5}$
You also know the length $c$ of the new vector.  From your example, even though you said $c=2$. What you really want is for $c$ to double the length of vector $s$.  That is, you want $c=2|B-A|=4\sqrt{5}$   Define a unit vector as follows: $$\mathbf{w}=(B-A)/\Vert(B-A)\Vert$$ The new point $C = A + c\cdot \mathbf{w}$. Defining $c$ this way is important in order to move away from having point A at $(0,0,0)$ $$\mathbf{w}=\frac{B-A}{\Vert B-A\Vert}=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}\\\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}\end{array}\right)$$ $$c=2|B-A|=4\sqrt{5}$$ $$\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 4\\ 8 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ 0 \end{array}\right)+c\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}\\ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} \end{array}\right)$$ That is, $$C=A+c\mathbf{w}$$

Comment: It is a bit unclear in your answer which quantities are vectors and which scalars, and which are points. Could you edit?

Comment: A and B are points but are treated as vector points.  That is, they have 3 components and are subtracted, multiplied, etc as if they were vectors.  $w$ will turn out to be a vector.  point A is treated as a vector - again 3 components.  Only $c$ is a scalar.

Comment: I am not able to make your solution work. See my updated question.

Comment: I see what you are doing.  I will update my answer in a few minutes.  It really won't change any, but will explain how to get your value.

Comment: I'm pretty bad at LaTex.  Takes a few tries.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you have defined $c$ differently from me. You defined $c$ as the magnitude of the new vector, while I defined $c$ as the ration of the magnitudes of the old and new vectors. If I convert your notation to my notation, I end up with a result that works. If you would convert your notation to my notation, then your answer would make perfect sense.

Comment: OK. I added a change of variable comment to the front of my answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No, I mean why can you not use the definitions that I have in my question? It makes no sense to use the same symbols with different definitions in your answer, even if you define them explicitly. Q and A should be coherent, right?

Comment: I don't want to re-typeset my answer.  You have understood it.  That is the purpose of this forum.

Comment: I disagree. Your answer is there to help anyone who reads my question. Now everyone will have to change the variables themselves. According to your logic, if it was only to me, you might as well just delete your answer, since I have understood it.